# Google Pub/Sub API limits

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Are there any limits on retrieval/update APIs provided?

I was able to find these docs:

- **https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas** :
  This contains info about throughputs and limits on the number of topics, subscriptions, and messages creation.
- **https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier** :
  This just says 10GB of messages per month.

What about the limits on retrieval/update APIs?

**For Example:**
Retrieving Topic with its name,
Updating a subscription.

Answer (score 1):

In the [quota page that you mentioned](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas#quotas), you have this

[image]

All the administrative operation (list, get, update, delete,...) have a quotas to 100 ops/s